# Login or email client-side validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have the next requirement for validation:

Login field - can contain an **alphanumeric string** or a **valid email**.

I think to use jQuery validation plugin, but can't find any info how to implement this OR condition.

There is a way to use a complex regexp (for ex. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6})+$/`), but it doesn't look like an elegant solution.

Is there a better way?

**UPD:** I've end up adding a custom method:

```
function alphanumericRegex(value) {
  return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}

function emailRegex(value) {
  return /^([a-z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,6})+$/i.test(value);
}

$.validator.addMethod("loginEmail", function(value, element) {          
  return this.optional(element) || alphanumericRegex(value) || emailRegex(value);
}, "Please enter letters, numbers or a valid email.");
```

Comment: You should show what you've done so far, even if it's not elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no rule exists that combines "valid email or alphanumeric" you'll have to create it yourself using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

Otherwise, there is a method call `pattern` included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) where you would use your custom regex as the parameter when declaring this method.

Comment: Thanks! `additional-methods.js` has some really useful methods (alphanumeric,  for example)